# URL com caracteres em Webview Android

Tags: android, webview

Tenho que exibir uma página em um webview android utilizando uma URL retornada pelo servidor. O problema se encontra no final da URL onde há dois ponto (..) mas quando passo a string para o webview esses pontos são ignorados e não é possível abrir carregar o conteúdo. 
Alguma sugestão de como proceder?
Exemplificando:

```
wvBillet = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb_billet);
 WebSettings ws = wvBillet.getSettings();
 ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 ws.setSupportZoom(false);
 ws.setTextZoom(0);
 wvBillet.loadUrl(urlbillet);
```

A URL em questão seria como essa:

https://homolog.bancoqualquer.com.br/api/bancoqualquer?token=aUxselZSMFM0c29seHdhdndoNm9TcVhBL0UxN1ptdmZIVmRCU3FYRHA1SzhMN2I4c3ZjN3dlV0tK..

Quando faço a chamada do webview e passo a URL ele lê até antes do .. - Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que possa ser feito?

Comment: Você pode nos mostrar a URL, ou o pedaço do seu código que está ignorando essa URL? Edite sua própria postagem pra mostrar.

Comment: O próprio browser(no meu caso Firefox) ignora o dois pontos.

Comment: @ramaral mesmo no navegador da minha máquina acaba sendo necessário os dois pontos mas o caso aqui é que preciso exibi-lo diretamente no webview (dentro do app).

Comment: Experimente trocar os pontos por %46%46

Comment: @ramaral Infelizmente mesmo usando sua sugestão ainda não houve progresso.